# How do I checkpoint a django sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 django database that is using WAL. In operation there are typically three files present: `db.sqlite3, db.sqlite3-shm, db.sqlite3-wal`.

To conveniently back up the database (when the service is stopped), I'd like to create a management command to checkpoint the sqlite database in order to write all the changes into `db.sqlite3` and delete the other two files.

While sqlite3 has a [checkpoint API](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/wal_checkpoint_v2.html), I don't know how to access this from django (or [python's sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sqlite3.html))

Comment: Recent enough versions of python support the backup api, which is about the only safe way to copy an open database. You linked to a really old version of the python sqlite3 docs. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html instead.

Comment: And if all connections were properly closed, the wal log should be removed by the last one, and you can just copy the database file normally in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the updated link. If only all connections were always properly closed ;)

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, you can use a pragma thus:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import connection


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Checkpoint the database, updating <db>.sqlite3 and removing <db>.sqlite3-wal and <db>.sqlite3-shm files'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('-cm', '--checkpoint_mode', default='TRUNCATE',
                            choices=['PASSIVE', 'FULL', 'RESTART', 'TRUNCATE'],
                            help='Checkpoint mode - See sqlite3 documentation for options (default is TRUNCATE)')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"PRAGMA wal_checkpoint({options['checkpoint_mode']});")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(f'{result}')
```